# Cycles Rendering Problems on the RX 5700 XT on Windows and Linux

Tags: cycles-render-engine, linux

I have a system with an Intel 8700k and an AMD RX 5700 XT.

The first image is the rendered with the CPU without issues:

[image: CPU render]

The second via GPU on Arch Linux with the newest updates:

[image: GPU render on Linux]

The third via GPU on Windows 10 also with the newest updates:

[image: GPU render on Windows 10]

As you can see there are problems rendering the image mainly in the face and grass. I tried the release directly from the blender website and from the repositories without a difference and sometimes my PC completely locks up.

Is this an error that I can fix or is this a driver problem where I have to wait until my graphic card drivers get updated?

Comment: The AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT appears to work properly with the Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.11.2 Optional (WHQL).

Answer (score 0):

It only works with the Enterprise Driver from AMD. https://www.amd.com/de/technologies/radeon-pro-software

With every other driver than that, I dont get any render on GPU running with my 5700xt GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 20.Q3.1 works with Blender 2.83.3 and 2.9.1, but it is not reliable with other applications. The RX 5700 XT is **NOT** on the compatible list. So the Enterprise Driver is just a stopgap measure so that you can keep on working with Blender and NOT the solution.

Comment: Sadly, after installing the amd pro driver a few months ago blender got really in stable and most menus didn't look right.
After trying it again today with both opencl-amd and the opencl-amdgpu-pro-pal drivers each time I start the render as soon as the first bounding boxes appear first blender doesn't respond than the entire system locks up. The best solution I could find was to use the GPU only for the view port.

Answer (score 0):

The question was originally posted when there were issues with AMD's graphics driver. Since then Blender has deprecated OpenCL support and replaced it with Heterogeneous Interface for Portability (HIP) for GPU rendering on AMD GPUs.

As documented in [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#hip-amd), GPU rendering with HIP requires Radeon Software 21.12.1 or Radeon PRO Software 21.Q4 on Windows and Radeon Software 22.10 or ROCm 5.1 on Linux.